# PHP Google adx RTB integration - Multiple Ads

Tags: php, python, protocol-buffers, google-ads-api, double-click-advertising

We are working on the Google ADX RTB integration with our AdServer by using the PHP and python as interpretor language. We using the Google protocol buffers, [PHP RTB server](https://github.com/chobie/php-rtb-server) for processing the bid requests.

- If matching ad data count is 1 then we considered as single ads and responded correctly.
- When we processing to multiple matching ad data, we are struggling to process the requests?
- How to setup the multiple ads responses with iframe template and its positions?

**Note:** We referred the Google Adx integration basic [documents](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/start)) and its google groups responses.

Comment: what is your concern ? Make question as you title

Comment: Yes, we mentioned the our clarification in it and added details of it in the description section